# JSON serialization of .NET DateTime round trip doesn't work

Tags: .net, json

If I save a .NET DateTime using System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer the deserialized version is an hour different than the original version.  Any ideas why?

EDIT: My workstation's time zone is UTC.

A NUnit test is below; note that the assertion works only after adding an hour.

```
    [Test]
    public void JsonSerializationOfDateTimesDoesntWork()
    {
        var originalDateTime = new DateTime(2011, 6, 20, 6, 5, 4, 3);
        const string fileName = "C:\\temp\\testDateTime.json";
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(fileName, false))
        {
            writer.Write(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(originalDateTime));
        }
        DateTime newDateTime;
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(fileName, false))
        {
            var readToEnd = reader.ReadToEnd();
            newDateTime = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<DateTime>(readToEnd);
        }

        Assert.AreEqual(originalDateTime, newDateTime.AddHours(1)); // !!
    }
```

Comment: Why is your sample code bothering to write this to disk? Just remember the string reference for deserialization...

Comment: (I very much doubt that your workstation's time zone is really UTC, by the way. I suspect it's the UK time zone, which is UTC in winter, but UTC+1 in summer - and the date you've given is in summer.)

Comment: @JonSkeet, belatedly: re: your second comment, if you want to post it as an answer I'll give you credit. That JSON serialization doesn't keep all of the DateTime state plus the daylight savings time offest was it.  re: item 1, the sample code is a not-completely simplified version of larger unit test in which the problem materialized.

Comment: I've added that to the bottom of my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The serializer apparently converts it to an *instant* in time, in the form of milliseconds since the unix epoch. In other words, it's effectively calling `ToUniversalTime()` first.

At that point, any information about the original "kind" of `DateTime` is lost.

On deserialization, the result is always a `DateTime` of kind UTC.

If you *start* with a `DateTime` with a kind of UTC, you'll round-trip. If you need to remember the kind as well, you'll need to keep that data separately. Just remember that local times can be inherently ambiguous.

```
using System;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

class Test
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var original = new DateTime(2011, 6, 20, 6, 5, 4, 3, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var text = serializer.Serialize(original);
        var parsed = serializer.Deserialize<DateTime>(text);
        Console.WriteLine("Original: {0} ({1})", original, original.Kind);
        Console.WriteLine("Text: {0}", text);
        Console.WriteLine("Parsed: {0} ({1})", parsed, parsed.Kind);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Original: 20/06/2011 06:05:04 (Utc)
Text: "\/Date(1308549904003)\/"
Parsed: 20/06/2011 06:05:04 (Utc)
```

Of course, this just highlights the [problems with `DateTime` being conceptually broken to start with](http://noda-time.blogspot.com/2011/08/what-wrong-with-datetime-anyway.html)...

EDIT: Also, as noted in comments, I very much doubt that your workstation's time zone is really UTC, by the way. I suspect it's the UK time zone, which is UTC in winter, but UTC+1 in summer - and the date you've given is in summer.

Answer (score 0):

use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` instead. It preserves the correct DateTime